# Override not working with bootstrap when fetching css from maxcdn server

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap framwork and trying to change few properties with navbar, like background color,

When I uses css from a local copy like, ./bootstrap.css override works fine or when I pasting whole css or just navbar css to liveweave CSS column override working.

But

when I am using maxcdn server like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Override is failing whether its liveweave or my pc, even after using !important override fails.

I am using

> navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top

classes

I am sure about what I said above, even before posting this question I visited at least 10 pages or similar question to find solution but none them used CSS from maxcdn server.

**Working Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
<script src="./google.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" ariazhaspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>
 </body>
 </html>
```

main.css

```
.navbar-default{
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a HTML example / JSFiddle of what is not working?

Comment: well I found out what was wrong, some how that optional theme css was overriding my css and yes I put my css or I linked my CSS after that theme, but it was overriding dont know how!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a local  css file for override. you must be sure this file is read after  the maxcdn...... file. the last one is the css element used

Answer (score -1):

Having the same issue... I noticed that, when viewing the maxcdn bootstrap.min.css in my text editor, the code stops running at ".glyphicon-phone:before{content:"\e145"}.glyphicon..." so I wonder if that is relating to the issue. Hoping that it gets sorted out soon!

Comment: This is a comment not an answer... You should remove this and comment under question